# Modulus a double precision floating point in MIPS?

Tags: assembly, floating-point, mips, modulus

OK, so basically I am having trouble getting one part of an RSA encryption program to work correctly.  I am writing the program in MIPS and am trying to take the modulus of a number raised to another number.  Using wikipedia's example I am raising 65^17, which gives 6.599E30 or so.  I now need to modulus this number by 3233 (again from wikipedia's example).

So far I have been unable to get this working.  I have tried dividing it by 3233, but can't figure out how to properly get the remainder, as when I truncate, I lose a large amount of the number

```
div.d   $f0, $f0, $f6   #f6 is currently 3233

trunc.w.d  $f8, $f0     #this is what is going wrong
cvt.d.w $f8, $f8        #when we do this truncation we end up with something other 
                        #than the number without the remainder

li $v0, 3
add.d  $f12, $f8, $f4   #using this to test print what is in $f8. $f4 is 0
syscall                 #When printed we get 2.14...E9


sub.d $f0, $f0, $f8


mul.d  $f0, $f0, $f6    #when we print $f0 we get 6.599...E30, but what we want is 2790
```

If anyone knows how to get this to properly give the value of 2790, as the final value of $f0, any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Ok so I was sort of able to solve it. This does the exponentiation then moduluses the number then repeats for a certain exponent.  Not sure how to solve the original question exactly, but this has the same effect.

```
loop2:
mul.d  $f0, $f0, $f2 #the exponentiation

div.d   $f0, $f0, $f6 #here we divide by the public key to modulus
floor.w.d  $f8, $f0  #We truncate this to get the number without the remainder
cvt.d.w $f8, $f8

sub.d $f0, $f0, $f8 #we subtract in order to get only the remainder
mul.d  $f0, $f0, $f6 #multiply the remainder by the divisor to get the modulus
round.w.d $f0, $f0  #round, don't floor because we sometimes get #'s that dont get 
                        #computed quite correctly and end up at x.999 instead of x+1 
                        #and those get floored down to x
cvt.d.w $f0,$f0

addi $t5, $t5, 1 # this is the incrementer
blt $t5, $t3, loop2 #raises input number to power
```

Comment: You can't to big integer arithmetic with floats; you will get utterly garbage results. You will need to rewrite this to use a big integer representation.